# Delete data older than 10 days in elasticsearch

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, search, kibana, elk

I am new to elasticsearch and I want to delete documents in my elasticsearch index which are older than 10 days. I want to keep only last 10 days of data.So is there any way to delete last 11nth day index automatically.
What I have tried..

```
DELETE logstash-*/_query
{
 "query": {
   "range": {
     "@timestamp": {
       "lte": "now-10d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error I'm getting while running on kibana dev tools

```
{
"error": "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/logstash-*/_query?pretty] and method [DELETE], 
allowed: [POST]",
"status": 405
}
```

Please help to resolve this issues.

Answer (score 14):

You need to leverage the [Delete by Query Endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html), like this:

```
use POST           use this endpoint
 |                      |
 V                      V
POST logstash-*/_delete_by_query
{
 "query": {
   "range": {
     "@timestamp": {
       "lte": "now-10d"
      }
    }
  }
}
  ^
  |
the query part is fine !!
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but its not working....   {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 0,
  "deleted" : 0,
  "batches" : 0,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
} . I'm getting such output and its not reflecting any changes.

Comment: Well with the response you showed that @Val 's answer fixed the original issue. Can you verify that there are even documents in that time range?

Comment: That means no documents matched the range. Replace `_delete_by_query` with `_search` and no documents should come up.

Answer (score 2):

I am describe diffent approach, then @Val have suggested. You can create 10 indexes (index per day) and each day delete one of the indexes - oldest one.

- Pros: it is very easy to delete or archive old data
- Cons: you need to
  rewrite your queries if you need to search all days data.

Comment: You can do same thing using ILM policy instead of through API each time.