# How to delete document in kibana by days or data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using AWS Elastic search. Right now my kibana has 0 free space. I want to delete documents that are older than 30days.

Is there any setting for that or query which can clear documents which is older than 30 days.

Comment: This thread might help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57975075/4604579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simple use the [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) to delete the documents which are older than 30 days :)